# CloudSql vs NDB Datastore for very frequent read/update

Tags: database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-sql, app-engine-ndb

I am new to Google app engine services. I am developing an application which requires very frequent reads and updates of existing values operations ( every 5 sec or so ).

I want to inquire which amongst CloudSql or NDB datastore is better suitable for this job.

Comment: This is off topic. Here you will get solutions to problem related to programming, not which one to choose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this job can be made easily by ndb store. You can take advantage from the built-in memcache system to save resources. CloudSQL can be also used with your GAE application but in this case you need to use the independent memcache system to save resources.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. 
The total data in my database is being updated every 5-10 secs (no additional entries added, just previous values updated), and the whole data is being read every 5 sec. Do you think we need memcache to cache entries which are being updated so frequently?

Comment: Hi, yes I think it's better to use memcache system in front of all read operation. Fundamentally, the ndb store system have a bult-in memcache system, so if you use that you don't care about memcache :)